# BitTorrent Bundles - how does paygate work? is there a spec?

Tags: bittorrent

There are various code libraries in different languages for interacting with the BitTorrent protocol. There's a specification here (not sure if best source):
https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification

I'm interested in the newish product built on top of BitTorrent protocol, by BitTorrent Inc the company: [Bundles](https://bundles.bittorrent.com/)

Famously Thom Yorke released his last album as a Bundle.

It allows the artist to offer some media for free, while keeping some behind a 'paygate' i.e. media you have to pay to unlock (there's also an 'emailgate' where content is unlocked by joining the artist's mailing list). The bundle itself is a torrent that can be downloaded via standard BitTorrent client software.

My question is: how does the paygate feature work?

Is it as simple as any file download? i.e. you pay to get access to download the torrent file and you could 'pirate' the bundle by sharing the torrent file, allowing others to download the media content?

Or is it more complicated?  Does it use any tricks in terms of the protocol to protect the gated content?